# Capture result of bash script into a Python program

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am interested in use a list of directories created in a bash script under the name `list_of_dirs_in_bash` and pass it to a list in my Python general program.

So, after doing in my Python script:

```
subprocess.call("my_bash_script.sh")
```

do something like:

```
list_of_dirs_in_python = list_of_dirs_in_bash
```

and then I can work with that list in Python. Sure it is not difficult but everything I have found is the other way around (from Python to bash). Thanks.

Comment: it is not very clear what you want to obtain. Did you try anything?

Comment: Rather than `subprocess.call`, try `subprocess.run` as [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.run). Pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` as an arg, then use the returned [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.CompletedProcess) to access the output of your bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: subprocess.**check_output**(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, encoding=None, errors=None, universal_newlines=None, timeout=None, text=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is what you need (simplest variant) for this task, as it will return the process' *stdout*. 
From there, decode and split the return value (string) to get individual lines.

Example (did everything from command line):

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> ls
> a.py        q049058700  q049654022  q051914879  q052090348  q053230645  q053781370  q054269984  q055357490  q056055568
> q038171543  q049499683  q051073129  q052051111  q052720961  q053626481  q054243176  q054306561  q055537728  sizes_mingwi686.exe
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]>
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> python3 -c "import subprocess;list_of_dirs_in_bash = subprocess.check_output(['ls']).decode().split('\n');print(list_of_dirs_in_bash)"
> ['a.py', 'q038171543', 'q049058700', 'q049499683', 'q049654022', 'q051073129', 'q051914879', 'q052051111', 'q052090348', 'q052720961', 'q053230645', 'q053626481', 'q053781370', 'q054243176', 'q054269984', 'q054306561', 'q055357490', 'q055537728', 'q056055568', 'sizes_mingwi686.exe', '']
> ```